# Get stats from Spring data

Tags: sql, entity-framework, spring-data

I’m trying to get stats from a DB using Spring data. The problem is that the result of my query doesn’t fit with any entity. For example: If I try to get the average of an employee’s sales by product, the information I get doesn’t fit with employee entity and product entity. I’ve tried to create a data base view with the stats and an entity which fits with the fields of the view but a view doesn’t have primary key so I don’t know how to create a repository to do query without a @Id field.
Any idea?
Thank you in advance for you time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. The @Id field is used to create, delete or update information in DB. It really don't care if I map a entity with a DB view because I can not change the information in an view.